# How to inherit template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am the Java guy and try to write inheritince over class template and I got a lot of error like: template specialization requires 'template<>' or use of class template 'array' requires template arguments. Can you guys help me to correct my faults about code or way of thinking? I have classes like this:

```
template <typename T>

class array {
public:
virtual void randomFunction() = 0;

protected:
T* values;
int size; // number of values
};
```

Here intArray.h

```
class intArray: public array<int>{
public:
  intArray();
  void randomFunction();
private:
};
```

Here intArray.cpp

```
intArray::intArray() {
this->size = 1;
this->values = new int[1];
}

void intArray::randomFunction() {
this->values[0] = 5; 
}
```

What I want is iterate over these objects like:

```
int main() {
  vector<array> arrayList;
  arrayList.push_back(intArray());
  arrayList.push_back(doubleArray());
  arrayList.push_back(stringArray());

  anotherFunction(&arrayList);
}

void anotherFunction(vector<array> *list) {
for(array a: (*list)) {
  a.randomFunction();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `array` is a class template, this `vector<array>` is not a valid type definition. As `std::vector` expects a type parameter.

If you are looking to accomplish type erasure, then that requires your class template to itself  inherit from a base:

```
class array_base {
  virtual void randomFunction() = 0;
  virtual ~array_base();
};

template <typename T>
class array : public array_base {
  // As before
};
```

That still isn't enough, since C++ isn't Java. We deal with objects, and to deal with them polymorphically, we need to explicitly use (smart-)pointers or references.

Bearing that in mind, your `vector` should now become this:

```
std:vector<std::unique_ptr<array_base>> arrayList;
arrayList.emplace_back(std::make_unique<intArray>());
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? The thing is I just don't know the type of values "T* values;" so should I define 3 different class which are array_base, array and intArray?

Comment: `T *values` depends on your template parameter. When you declare `array<int>` it creates a new c++ class on the spot. I'd say `intArray` is redundant.

Comment: Ok here is the last question there will be 10 classes. All of the class differ from each other with size and value type such as; intArrayWithSizeOne, doubleArrayWithSizeFive, stringArrayWithSizeNine. Should I keep going with same data structure so I will define 10 class and array and array_base. or should I change variable T* values to void *values and then define values in derived class? Sorry for dumb question.

Comment: @Nick I'm not sure I follow. But if your size is a compile time constant, then you can simply declare your template as `template<typename T, std::size_t size> array { T arr_[size];  };` And spare yourself all those dynamic allocations.

Comment: Thanks @StoryTeller